# Error in displaying where there's an a array inside of the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is what the data shows inside the console:

[image]

I tried displaying it with these but it failed

```
 {Object.entries(value).map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
          <p key={key}>
            <li>
              {key}
              {value}
              {console.log(value.id)} //this will show as undefined
            </li>
          </p>
        );
      })}
```

`{value}` will show this error :

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {color, quantity}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

`{value.id}` or the `{value.name}` will show as undefined

With the map, it will say that `value.map` is not a function

```
 {value.map((value, key) => (
    <>
      <div>{value.id}</div>
      <div>{value.name}</div>
    </>
  ))}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/display-the-manipulated-data-dy204r

Comment: What exactly do you want to display on the screen?

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni All of the data inside the picture that I've posted

Comment: You should improve the structure of your data so that there's less overhead while rendering it. In your `helperFx` function what are you trying to achieve? You're comparing a  property with itself in the `if` block that always evaluates to true. Could you clearly describe what the collection should hold? So, that necessary revamps can be made?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/display-the-manipulated-data-forked-0710q6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object has a complex structure, and in order to iterate, you need to check if one of the items is `Array` using `Array.isArray()`, if yes, then loop them and use, else use the properties directly

---

Below is the working code of the mock of your object and iteration. I have just logged the values, you can use them in any way you want

```js
let myObj = {
  s: [{
    color: 'a',
    q: '8'
  }, {
    color: 'b',
    q: '2'
  }],
  name: 'Anne',
  id : 18
}

Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (Array.isArray(myObj[key])) {
    myObj[key].forEach(function (item, index) {
      console.log(item.color);
      console.log(item.q);
    });
  }
  else
    console.log(myObj[key])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
{Object.entries(value).map((v, key) => {
    return (
      <p key={key}>
        <li>
          {key}
          {v.name}
          {console.log(v.id)} //this will show as undefined
        </li>
      </p>
    );
  })}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).